# $\sigma$-algebras on a countable set is generated by partitions of the set

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a countable set, show that every $\sigma$-algebra is generated by a partition of $X$.

I don't even know how to start. I 've been stuck on this problem for a long time. Any hints are welcomed.

Comment: Hint: Given a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, we want to find a bunch of small building blocks for our $\sigma$-algebra which partition $X$.  For a given $x\in X$, consider the intersection of all elements of your $\sigma$-algebra which contain $x$.  See if you can prove that sets of this type are still in your $\sigma$-algebra.  Also, see if you can prove that for different elements $x$ and $y$, the sets I described are either disjoint or equal.

Comment: @JoshKeneda I think this works if $X$ is finite. But there are some trouble in the case $X$ is infinite. Since there could uncountably many sets in the $\sigma$-algebra which contain $x$, then the intersection may not lie in the $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Sure, it's at first an uncountable intersection.  But I claim that, since $X$ is countable, you can express this intersection as a countable intersection of sets in your $\sigma$-algebra.  It's just about finding a clever way to rephrase the sets I described.

Comment: Try to do it without this additional hint, but if you need it, read on.  Fix $x\in X$.  For $y\in X$, either your $\sigma$-algebra can tell the difference between $x$ and $y$ or it can't.  If it can, let $L_{x, y}$ be a set in your $\sigma$-algebra which includes $x$ but not $y$.  If it can't, let $L_{x, y} = X$.  What is $\cap_{y\in X} L_{x, y}$?

Comment: @JoshKeneda That is a good point, really elegant. Thank you.

Comment: Anytime!  Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @JoshKeneda: Could you turn your comments into an answer so that this question isn't marked as _unanswered_ anymore?  Thanks!

Comment: @JoshKeneda Could you help me understand why $\cap L_{x,y}$ is well-defined? i.e Why doesn't it depend on the choice of the set which contains x  but not y?

Comment: @BlueBuck Sure.  Good question.  Suppose $\cap L'_{x,y}$ is another such set, and let $z\in \cap L'_{x,y}$.  Then every set in the $\sigma$-algebra which contains $x$ must also contain $z$.  In particular, $z\in L_{x,y}$ for all $y$, so $z \in \cap L_{x, y}$.  By symmetry, we get the reverse inclusion, so $\cap L'_{x,y} = \cap L_{x,y}$.

The heuristic is that $\cap L_{x,y}$ is just the collection of points that are inseparable from $x$ from the $\sigma$-algebra's perspective.  And this description of $\cap L_{x,y}$ makes it a little more clear that it won't depend on the choice of $L_{x,y}$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sketch of proof:  For each $x\in X$, we want to find the smallest element in our $\sigma$-algebra which contains $x$.  Then these building blocks will serve to partition $X$ and generate our $\sigma$-algebra.

Fix $x\in X$.  For $y\in X$, either our $\sigma$-algebra can separate $x$ from $y$ or it can't.  If it can, let $L_{x, y}$ be a set in our $\sigma$-algebra which contains $x$ and does not contain $y$.  If it can't, let $L_{x, y} = X$.  Then $\cap_{y \in X} L_{x, y}$ is the smallest set in the $\sigma$-algebra which contains $x$ (formally, it's equal to the intersection over all elements in the $\sigma$-algebra containing $x$ - I'll omit that proof).

If $z \in \cap_{y \in X} L_{x, y}$, then $\cap_{y \in X} L_{z, y} \subset \cap_{y \in X} L_{x, y}$ since $\cap_{y \in X} L_{z, y}$ is the smallest measurable set containing $z$.  Applying this symmetrically, we must have $\cap_{y \in X} L_{x, y} = \cap_{y \in X} L_{z, y}$.  So these small sets are either the same or disjoint, and thus they form a partition of $X$ which generates the $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Can you give an example to show that no such clever argument will work when X is uncountably infinite?

Comment: Sure.  Consider the Borel measurable sets on $\mathbb{R}$.  Suppose that this $\sigma$-algebra is generated by a partition of $\mathbb{R}$.  We note that the singleton sets $\{x\}$ are Borel measurable, which means that $\{x\}$ must belong to the partition for all $x$.  Therefore the generating partition is just the partition into singletons, which generates the discrete $\sigma$-algebra.  But not all sets are Borel measurable.  Contradiction.

Comment: But if X is uncountable, then the sigma-algebra generated by singletons is not the power set, but rather the sigma-algebra of countable and cocountable sets.   So don't we need to know that there are non-Borel-measurable sets in the co-countable sigma-algebra?  How to see that?

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I was taking the atomic algebra (allowing arbitrary unions) generated by the partition instead of the usual $\sigma$-algebra.  If you just want to see that the co-countable $\sigma$-algebra and the Borel $\sigma$-algebra are unequal, then note that $[0,1]$ is in the Borel algebra but isn't countable/co-countable.  All elements of the co-countable $\sigma$-algebra will of course be Borel measurable, though.

Comment: In other words, the Borel algebra is strictly finer than the $\sigma$-algebra generated by our partition, so the Borel algebra isn't generated by a partition of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How do you know that this partition generates the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$? i.e. how do you know that for $L:= \{ \bigcap_{y \in X}L_{x,y}: x \in X \}$, $\sigma (L) = \Sigma$? I was only able to show that $\sigma (L) \subset \Sigma$, since $\Sigma$ itself is a $\sigma$-algebra which contains $L$.

Comment: @Einsteinwasmyfather For any $A \in \Sigma,$ you have $$A = \cup_{x \in A} \cap_{y \in X} L_{x, y}$$