# How to construct a partition of X given a sigma-algebra on X (when X countably infinite)

Tags: measure-theory, set-partition

I am attempting to construct a partition of a countable set X, given a sigma-algebra on that set.  Eventually I will want partitions of X to be in 1-1 correspondence with sigma-algebras on X.  See my question below:

> Say $X$ is countable. We want to show $\sigma$-algebras on $X$ are in one to one correspence with partitions of $X$.
>
> Given a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$ on $X$, and given $x\in X$, we can form $$X_x=\bigcap_{A\in\mathscr{A}:x\in A}A\;.$$ This could be an uncountable intersection, meaning the result $X_x$ need not be an element of $\mathscr{A}$.
>
> However, is there still a way to show these sets of the form $X_x$ do partition $X$? Or need I construct my partition in some other way?

Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RUpR.jpg).

Comment: Okay, so my question was already answered here...

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931744/sigma-algebras-on-a-countable-set-is-generated-by-partitions-of-the-set