# Show the sigma algebra of a countable set is generated by a partition

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

> A $\sigma$-algebra $F$ is said to be generated by a partition if there
>     is some partition $\{B_i\}$ of $\Omega$ so that every set $A$ in $F$ is a
>     union of some parts in the partition, and every such union in in $F$.
>     Show that any $\sigma$-algebra on a countable set $\Omega$ is generated
>     by a partition of $\Omega$.

Proof: Let $\Omega$ be a countable set and $F$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$, then $F$ $\subset$ $2^\Omega$. Let $x\in\Omega$, consider $\cap_i A_i$ such that $x\in A_i$ for all $i$, and $A_i \in F$. Note there maybe uncountably many $A_i \in F$ such that $x \in A_i$, but since $\Omega$ is countable, $\cap_i A_i$ can be written as an intersection of sets in $F$, so $\cap A_i \in F$.

I know that I need to work work with the intersections and see if the sigma algebra can or cannot distinguish $x,y \in \Omega$. But my question is how do I prove the intersections of all sets $A_i$ containing $x$ can be written as intersections of sets in $F$?

Comment: Can someone give me a hint? Thank you.

Comment: "how do I prove the intersections of all sets Ai containing x can be written as intersections of sets in F?" This is deeply confused: the intersection of all subsets of Ω containing x simply does not enter the picture, only the intersection of all sets in F containing x does.

Comment: @Did I mean there may be infinitely many sets in $F$ that contains element x

Comment: I want to show the collection of $A_i$ is countable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to the proof in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/932678/250955.

For every $x,y \in \Omega$, let $L_{x,y}$ be any set from $F$ that contain $x$ but does not contain $y$, if such set exists, and $\Omega$ otherwise. I guess you want to prove that
$$\bigcap_{y \in \Omega} L_{x,y} = \bigcap_{\substack{A \in F \\ x \in A}} A.$$
Indeed,

- $\rm{LHS} \supset \rm{RHS}$ (since $x \in L_{x,y} \in F$ for every $y \in \Omega$).
- On the other hand, if $z \in \rm{LHS}$ then also $z \in L_{x,z}$ and this is possible only if every set in $F$ that contain $x$ also contains $z$. But then, $z \in \rm{RHS}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was really helpful.

Comment: could you please tell me why on the RHS we can only consider countably many sets A that is in $F$, instead of all sets that contains x (which we may have unaccountably many)?

Comment: @Rann On the RHS we have intersection of all (possibly uncountable many) sets from $F$ that contain $x$, but it is equal to intersection of countably many sets $L_{x,y} \in F$, $y \in \Omega$ on the LHS (since $\Omega$ is countable).

Comment: how do we see that? Can we prove that it is equal to the intersection of countably many sets in $F$?

Comment: @Rann Well, that is the only thing proved in the answer you accepted: that (possibly) uncountable union on the RHS of displayed equation is the same set as a countable union on the LHS.