# General form of $\sigma$-algebra of countable set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, set-partition

Let $\Omega$ be a countable set. I want to show that every $ \sigma $-algebra $\Sigma$ on $\Omega$ is of the form

\begin{equation}
\{ \bigcup_{k \in K'}A_k : K' \subset K \},
\end{equation}

where $A_k$ is a finite or countable partition of $\Omega$.

I already know that for a countable partition $(X_n)_n$ the following holds:
\begin{equation}
\sigma((A_n)_n) = \{ \bigcup_{n \in J}X_n : J \subset \mathbb{N} \}.
\end{equation}
So my idea was finding a partition $L$ of $\Omega$ such that is generates the whole $\sigma$-algebra (i.e. $\sigma(L) = \Sigma$). I have found in the following two links what I needed:

[Show the sigma algebra of a countable set is generated by a partition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441596/show-the-sigma-algebra-of-a-countable-set-is-generated-by-a-partition?rq=1)

[$\sigma$-algebras on a countable set is generated by partitions of the set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931744/sigma-algebras-on-a-countable-set-is-generated-by-partitions-of-the-set/932678#932678)

So my partition of $\Omega$ is $L:= \{\bigcap_{y \in \Omega}L_{x,y} : x \in \Omega\}$, which was proven to be a partition and described in the above two links.

However, I cannot seem to prove that $\sigma(L) = \Sigma$ holds. I only know for sure that $\sigma(L) \subset \Sigma$, because $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains each element of $L$. The other inclusion seems hard to prove, since I have to show that every element $A \in \Sigma$ can be written as a countable union/intersection of these minimal "building blocks". So my question is, in the second link I provided, why can we conclude that this partition generates the whole sigma algebra ($\sigma(L) = \Sigma$)?

Comment: For any $A \in \Sigma$, $A = \cup_{x \in A} \cap_{y \in A^c} L_{x, y}$.

Comment: I get why $A \subset \cup_{x \in A} \cap_{y \in A^c} L_{x, y}$, however I cannot seem to prove the other inclusion. Also, I need $A$ to be a countable union of sets in $L$, but this is not a countable union of sets in $L$ because the intersections goes over $A^c$ (while I need them to go over the whole set $\Omega$).

Comment: To address the first point, to show that the reverse inclusion holds, it suffices to prove, for any $x \in A$ and $z \in \cap_{y \in A^c} L_{x, y}$, we have $z \in A$. Assume to the contrary that $z \in A^c$. As $x \in A$, $z \in A^c$, and $A \in \Sigma$, we have $\Sigma$ separates $x$ and $z$, whence $L_{x, z}$, by definition, excludes $z$. But as $z \in A^c$, $\cap_{y \in A^c} L_{x, y} \subseteq L_{x, z}$ must exclude $z$ as well, which is a contradiction. So $z \in A$.

Comment: Replacing $A^c$ with $\Omega$ in the intersection actually gives you the same result. It’s clear that, as $x \in \cap_{y \in \Omega} L_{x, y}$, we have $A \subseteq \cup_{x \in A} \cap_{y \in \Omega} L_{x, y}$. Conversely, $\cap_{y \in \Omega} L_{x, y} \subseteq \cap_{y \in A^c} L_{x, y}$, so $\cup_{x \in A} \cap_{y \in \Omega} L_{x, y} \subseteq \cup_{x \in A} \cap_{y \in A^c} L_{x, y} = A$.

Comment: Thank you very much @DavidGao

Comment: This really helped me understand this problem and the notion of sigma-algebra's in general. I have one final question however, how does one come up with such a partition in the first place? Does this take a lot of exercise with such problems or does one need to be creative enough to come up with such constructions ? I know this is a somewhat tough question to answer, but any tips in general would be welcome :)

Comment: In this case, it's more that we already have a mental picture as to what such a partition would look like. For countable $\Omega$, we already expect the $\sigma$-algebra to sort of look like the $\sigma$-algebra of all subsets of $\Omega$, modulo the fact that certain distinct elements of $\Omega$ may not be distinguished by $\Sigma$. And for each $x \in \Omega$, the collection of elements indistinguishable from $x$ is exactly $\cap_{A \in \Sigma, x \in A} A$. It is quite clear that $\{\cap_{A \in \Sigma, x \in A} A: x \in \Omega\}$ is a countable partition of $\Omega$.

Comment: The issue is, of course, that $\cap_{A \in \Sigma, x \in A} A$ might not be in $\Sigma$ since the intersection is an uncountable intersection even if $\Omega$ is countable, as $\Sigma$ could be uncountable. The reason we constructed these $L_{x, y}$ is really to show that, when $\Omega$ is countable, this is not an issue. The observation here is that you don't really need to take the intersection of all $A \in \Sigma$ with $x \in A$, you just need, for each $y \notin \cap_{A \in \Sigma, x \in A} A$, an element of $\Sigma$ that contains $x$ but not $y$.

Comment: And that is exactly the $L_{x, y}$ we constructed. The point here is that we then have $\cap_{A \in \Sigma, x \in A} A$ equals $\cap_{y \in \Omega} L_{x, y}$, which is now a countable intersection of elements of $\Sigma$ and therefore in $\Sigma$ itself. This is the intuition behind the construction of this partition.

Comment: As an extra point, let me point out that without the assumption that $\Omega$ is countable, $\cap_{A \in \Sigma, x \in A} A$ may not be in $\Sigma$. As an example, fix any uncountable set $I$ and let $\Omega = \{0, 1\}^I$. Then you can verify that $\Sigma = \{K \times \{0, 1\}^{I \setminus L}: K \subseteq \{0, 1\}^L, L \subseteq I, L\textrm{ is countable}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. For any $x \in \Omega$, $\cap_{A \in \Sigma, x \in A} A = \{x\}$ but $\{x\} \notin \Sigma$.

Comment: So I guess this is more like an intuition and experience thing here? This is really that intuition and experience already tell you what your partition should look like and the obstacle here is to come up with a way (namely these $L_{x, y}$) to show that this intuition works as intended.