# Let X be a countable set, show that every σ-algebra is generated by a partition of X.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I know this question has been asked before, but I don't understand one step in the proof that Josh Keneda kindly gave in the sketch proof found here:

[$\sigma$-algebras on a countable set is generated by partitions of the set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931744/sigma-algebras-on-a-countable-set-is-generated-by-partitions-of-the-set)

Theorem:
Let $\Omega$ be a countable set, and $(\Omega,F)$ be a measurable space. Then $\exists$ a countable partition of $\Omega$, say
\begin{equation*}
\left\{\Omega_i : i=1,2,...\right\}
\end{equation*}
Such that $F = \sigma\left( \left\{\Omega_i : i=1,2,....\right\}\right)$

Proof:
Since $\Omega$ is countable, we may write $\Omega:=\{\omega_1,\omega_2,...\}$. Let us fix $n,m$ and define the measurable sets. 
\begin{equation}
\Omega_n:=\bigcap_{\substack{A\in F \\ \omega_n\in A}} A \qquad \text{ and } \qquad \Omega_m:= \bigcap_{\substack{B\in F \\ \omega_m\in B}} B
\end{equation}

Then observe that if $m\ne n$ and $\omega_n \in \Omega_n$ it follows that $\Omega_m\subseteq \Omega_n$. To see this more clearly, by definition:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
&\omega_m\in A, \quad \forall \text{ measurable subsets }A\in F \text{ such that } \omega_n\in A\\
\Longrightarrow \quad & \{A\in F: \omega_n\in A\} = \{A\in F: \omega_n \text{ and } \omega_m\in A\}\subseteq \{B\in F : \omega_m\in B\}\\
\Longrightarrow \quad & \Omega_m\subseteq \Omega_n
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\

However this is where I get stuck!

Supposedly by using "symmetry" I am able to obtain that $\Omega_n\subseteq \Omega_m$.

To do this I THINK I would need to need the that fact that $\omega_n\in \Omega_m$...but I cannot justify to my self why:

\begin{equation}
\omega_m\in \Omega_n \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \omega_n\in \Omega_m
\end{equation}

Because it appears to me to be the case that if $\omega_m\in \Omega_n$ there is no reason that $\Omega_n$ is still a atom of the $\sigma$-field $F$, let alone a partition of $\Omega$.

Am I being silly?!?!

Thanks a bunch in advanced.

Comment: I think you have missed an essential point in the construction of the sets $\Omega_n$ namely that every intersection in the link is over a countable set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\omega_n\notin\Omega_m$; then there is some $A\in F$ such that $\omega_m\in A$, and $\omega_n\notin A$. But then $\Omega\setminus A\in F$, $\omega_n\in\Omega\setminus A$, and $\omega_m\notin\Omega\setminus A$, so $\omega_m\notin\Omega_n$.

Comment: Thank you so much Professor Scott - I must've just been staring at it for too long! Feel really stupid now haha

Comment: @SiuyuatWong: You're very welcome. (I think that we've all had that feeling a time or two.)